# Erro Phonegap Ajax

Tags: jquery, apache-cordova

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para enviar e receber registros em tempo real quando testei o aplicativo no navegador ele estava funcionando normalmente, mas quando eu converti ele apk e instalei no meu celular ele estava dando erro no ajax, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sys/fetchdata.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { tipo: "insere_evento",
            tipo_evento: tipo_evento,
            id_user:session_user,
            lat: lat,
            lon: lon
          },success: function(retorno){
             if(retorno.status == "ok"){
                alert("Evento registrado com sucesso");
             }else{
                alert("Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente mais tarde");
             }
          },error: function(e){
                alert("Falha ao conectar ao servidor, tente novamente mais tarde");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Se você estiver usando o Cordova 4.1+ e tentou instalar o App no Android, pode ser um problema com WhiteList. Dê uma olhadinha aqui: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: obrigado, era problema de whitelist mesmo, consegui resolver

Comment: Qual erro ocorre?
Dá um console.log ou alert no xhr de retorno do ajax.

Comment: então meu amigo, o erro estava na versão que eu estava usando o jquery, eu estava usando a versão pc até que tive a ideia de mudar pra o jquery mobile e funcionou, foi burrice minha mesmo, mas obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Por padrão, o PhoneGap possui um "bloqueio" ao acesso de paginas da internet pelo aplicativo. Mas para quem necessita desse acesso, ele na sua própria documentação possui um guia explicando como resolver isso. Segue o link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#supported-cordova-platforms Execute os seguintes comandos no seu terminal, no diretório de seu aplicativo: $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist $ cordova prepare
(Se for windows, não precisa do $) E adicione a seguinte linha no seu `config.xml`: <allow-navigation href="*" /> Essa linha, b